# ImportError: The 'enchant' C library was not found and maybe needs to be installed. New

Tags: python, pyenchant, enchant

I want to import enchant, but I get this error

```
Python 3.9.7 (default, Sep 16 2021, 08:50:36) 
[Clang 10.0.0 ] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import enchant
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/enchant/__init__.py", line 81, in <module>
    from enchant import _enchant as _e
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/enchant/_enchant.py", line 157, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: The 'enchant' C library was not found and maybe needs to be installed.
See  https://pyenchant.github.io/pyenchant/install.html
for details
```

I used these commands

```
brew install enchant  
pip install pyenchant
pip install enchant
```

Comment: Since you're using Conda, why not `conda install enchant` (or whatever the appropriate name is). That is what Conda is for, the additional C libraries.

Comment: You may need to use the conda-forge channel to install (py)enchant: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pyenchant

Comment: Been on solving environment for 5 or 10 mins, will wait Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): | WARNING conda.models.version:get_matcher(537): Using .* with relational operator is superfluous and deprecated and will be removed in a future version of conda. Your spec was 1.7.1.*, but conda is ignoring the .* and treating it as 1.7.1
done
Solving environment: |

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `PYENCHANT_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable to point to the library installed by Homebrew, like this:

```bash
$ PYENCHANT_LIBRARY_PATH=$(brew --prefix enchant)/lib/libenchant-2.dylib python
```

Now the import works:

```
Python 3.11.5 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Aug 27 2023, 03:33:12) [Clang 15.0.7 ] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import enchant
>>>
```

Comment: File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ctypes/__init__.py", line 382, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: dlopen(/opt/homebrew/opt/enchant/lib/libenchant-2.dylib, 0x0006): tried: '/opt/homebrew/opt/enchant/lib/libenchant-2.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')),

Comment: '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/opt/enchant/lib/libenchant-2.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/opt/enchant/lib/libenchant-2.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/enchant/2.5.0/lib/libenchant-2.2.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/Cellar/enchant/2.5.0/lib/libenchant-2.2.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/enchant/2.5.0/lib/libenchant-2.2.dylib' (mach-o file,

Comment: but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64'))

Comment: I added the error message above

Comment: @Cauder Are you using a x86_64 Python on a ARM64 macOS? What's the output of runing `file $(which python)`?

Comment: /opt/anaconda3/bin/python: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64

Comment: @Cauder You should install an ARM64 Python (or ARM64 Anaconda) if you are using macOS on a ARM64 Mac. On the [Anaconda official Download page](https://www.anaconda.com/download), choose "Download for Mac (M1/M2)".